# TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 upgrade error

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Trying to upgrade my TFS from 2010 to 2013.  Upgraded the SQL database from SQL 2008 to SQL 2014 (required for the upgrade) and then uninstalled TFS 2010.  Now when I try and run the upgrade wizard the readiness check gives me the following errors:

**TF400129**: Error from readiness check: Verifying that the team project collection has space for new system fields

**TF400129**: Error from readiness check: Verifying that the team project collection doesn't have fields conflicting with new work item system fields

**TF400927**: The following team project collection is in detached state: Broken Collection. Sql Server hosting the database: BABYLON. Database name: Tfs_DefaultCollection.

Looking in the log I found this:

*[Error  @23:14:35.106] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Fields'.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException ex, QueryExecutionState queryState)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.AdminSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteScalar(SqlQuery sqlQuery, SqlInfoMessageEventHandler infoMessageHandler)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.SqlHandler.ExecuteScalar[T](ISqlConnectionInfo connectionInfo, SqlQuery sqlQuery, SqlInfoMessageEventHandler infoMessageHandler)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.VerifyFieldLimitNotExceededInAllTpcs.Run(ActivityContext context)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Engine.AdminNode.RunNode()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Engine.AdminNode.Run(String& message, Boolean& continueOnError)*

Anyone got any ideas where I'm going wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so I evidentally had a collection that was broken and needed to be detached and deleted before I could do the upgrade.  This required me to re-install TFS2010, restore from my backup, detach and delete the offending collection, and then go through the upgrade again.

Answer (score 0):

First error (TF400129) means that you have too many work item fields in one of the TFS 2010 collections. SQL server has a limit (1024) on the number of columns you can have in a table. Every time you add a new field to TFS project a new column gets added to the WorkItemsAre/WorkItemsLatest/WorkItemsWere tables. You can check the number of columns we have  now by running this SQL query in the TFS collection database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'WorkItemsAre'
```

TF400129 error is related to the first one. What happens here is that during the upgrade TFS tries to add several new system fields. Upgrade wizard checks that you have enough space to add them (apparently you don't, that's why you got TF400129) and it also checks that existing field names don't conflict with the new system fields it will add during the upgrade.

Regarding TF400927: did you detach the collection before uninstalling TFS 2010? You don't need to do it for upgrade.

Comment: I did not detach anything before the upgrade.  I will check the number of fields and see if that's it.

Comment: I checked the database and ran your query... it returned 44, so it's well within the 1024 limit.  Any other ideas?  I'm starting to think I will have to reinstall 2010 at this point.  :(

Comment: I looked at the error you got - can you check that you have Fields table in the collection database (Tfs_DefaultCollection)? If you do, check the number of rows there: 'select count(*) from Fields' I think it's a better way to check the number of fields you have in the collection.